# EditText Backcolor crashes

Tags: android, android-edittext, colordrawable

Can anyone advise why the simple program keeps on crashing?

```
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener_button1 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ColorDrawable drawable = (ColorDrawable)editText1.getBackground();

        }

    };
```

Comment: Have you looked inside Logcat on the bottom of Android Studio?
My guess is that you don't actually have ColorDrawable in the background of editText1 so the cast fails.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable

Comment: So my assumption was correct, you have InsetDrawable there instead of ColorDrawable.
What do you want to do with the drawable? Perhaps InsetDrawable can do what you need it to.

Comment: Thank you! At least using InsetDrawable does not crush the app. My initial intention was to get at first the edittext current background color and after that to change it by the color I choose.

Comment: I guess if you set it initially to a color then it will work, perhaps in xml: `android:background="@color/initial_color"`

Comment: Szymon, thank you very much! It seems like indeed it is started to work. How can I increase your status here? :)

Comment: You can add upvotes on my comments I suppose :) Or accept my answer, coming in a minute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As uncovered in comments, you are casting an InsetBackground to a ColorBackground, which fails.

To get proper results, you need to set `android:background="@color/initial_color"` to the EditText in xml.